# Error attaching mdf file to sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I want to attach mdf file to sql server 2008 R2 I get the following error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Attach database failed for Server 'BABAK-PC'. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1+((KJ_RTM).100402-1540+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1+%28%28KJ_RTM%29.100402-1540+%29&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> Unable to open the physical file
>   "C:\madrase\madrase\entekhab_vahed\entekhab_vahed.mdf". Operating
>   system error 5: "5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason:
>   15105)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5120&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> OK

In other system I can attach this mdf file.  Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA SE site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if sql server service account has full permission on the drive / folder where you copied the mdf file. (Right Click on the drive / folder  >> Properties >> Security)

Comment: i check it but error still !! http://i61.tinypic.com/ohicnp.jpg

Comment: Then see if the user you used when you connected through management studio have the full control (windows user or sql server user) ... either run ssms as administrator